# How to Set default text among many using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Following JSON  included in my database.

No.s 10, 20, 30, 40 are the serial no. and having three languages English(en), French(fr) and Spanish(esp)

```
10: en:Proposal Details english
10: fr:Proposal Details french
10: esp:Proposal Details spanish 

20: fr:Select Fields . french 
20: esp:Select Fields. spanish 
20: en:Select Fields. english 

30: en:Pricing Guideline 
30: esp:null 
30: fr:null 

40: esp:null 
40: fr:null
```

40: en:Proposal Name*

**Updated Code :**

I am trying to do is :

```
obj = [{serial_no : '10', title : 'title1', lang : 'en'}, 
       {serial_no : '10', title : '', lang : 'fr'}, 
       {serial_no : '10', title : '', lang : 'esp'}, 
       {serial_no : '20', title : 'title4', lang : 'en'}]
```

In this **obj**, language : **'fr'** and **'esp'** for serial_no 10 are having title blank.

So I want those **blank value** should take value of **serial_no** 10 whose title is **'title1'**

for this I am trying with :

```
for(i = 0 ; i< obj.length; i++){    
    arr = obj[i]["serial_no"];      
    if(obj[i]["serial_no"] == arr && obj[i]["lang"] == 'en'){
        english_title = obj[i]["title"];
    }
    if(obj[i]["serial_no"] == arr){
        if(obj[i]["lang"] == 'fr' && obj[i]["title"] == ''){
            obj[i]["title"] = english_title         
        }    
    }       
}
```

How can I go for it ?
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

At the place where you extract the string for the current language, look at the string you find. If it is `null`, get the string for English instead.

This logic should be wrapped in a function that is used everywhere a language specific string is required.

Comment: Can you give any example? if possible

Comment: @eegloonew: You don't say anything specific what you are doing with you strings or in your javascript, so how should I know what fits your code?

Comment: I am having array in which having fields : serial no., language, title. Including three languages, english language title is present and other laguages french and spanish are having text also and some are blank. So if french and spanish languages are blank then need to take english language title. This is I am doing. And three languages are having common serial no. So is this Ok?

Comment: I have updated question code. Can you please take a look, if possible?